# Gnome Panel Crashes

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel

I recently started to experience a problem with Ubuntu 11.10 GNOME Panel. When I click on the standard sound icon over there, the whole panel disappears and reloads in a second or so, and I think its crashing.

1. If this is a known bug, do you know the url of corresponding entry at Launchpad?
2. What is the packeage responsible for running the panel?
3. Where can I find its (the panel's) logs?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question is really a bug report, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is already a bug report for this problem in Launchpad, but you should mark it as affecting you in order to fix it in Ubuntu 11.10:

- [Bug 882109](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/882109);
- It affects indicator-sound;
- If you are not sure if this is the bug, please read the [official Ubuntu documentation on how to report bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)  and file a new one.

Comment: This might or might not be his crasher, maybe instead show him how to turn apport on so the tool can catch the crash, he can then submit it and let launchpad do all the work!

Comment: That is the bug I am experincing. The interesting thing is that I did not appear till some point. I will play around with some settings to check out what might cause it.